# Exists or put value in preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this regex which I use with `preg_match()`:

```
^#admin#products#p-([0-9]+)$/
```

How to make in this regex if `p-([0-9]+)` not found put `p-1`?

## Edit

For:

```
preg_match(^#admin#products#p-([0-9]+)$/, '/^admin#products#p-3$/', $matches)
```

$mathes will be

```
array(
    [0] => '3'
)
```

And for

```
preg_match(^#admin#products#p-([0-9]+)$/, '/^admin#products$/', $matches)
```

I want $mathes to be

```
array(
    [0] => '1'
)
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the requirement? What do you mean by "put"?

Comment: If not found p-([0-9]+), so "find" p-1. Like: If not found, automatically make exists p-1

Comment: Ok, but `p-[0-9]+` already matches `p-1`. What does "make exists" mean? Provide some sample strings and expected output for each of them. Maybe you want to match 0 or more digits? `p-[0-9]*`? Try `^#admin#products#p-([0-9]*)$`

Comment: I edited. Better now?

Comment: Matches is a reference, so just set it before: `$matches[0] = '1';`

Comment: I want it only if there is no p-([0-9]+) out there :(

Comment: Yes, correct.  Did you try it???

Comment: What to try. I ask here how to do that? :))

Comment: Check [this approach](https://ideone.com/9nc3oy). I just do not understand what pattern you are seeking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I mention in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706122/exists-or-put-value-in-preg-match/50706671#comment88422206_50706122) is that you may set `$result` output variable to `1` and use a pattern with the `p-([0-9]+)` wrapped inside an optional group: `(?:p-([0-9]+))?`. If the Group 1 value is not empty, set it to `$matches[1]`, else, it will remain `1`:

```
$res = '1';
if (preg_match('~\^admin#products#(?:p-([0-9]+))?~', '/^admin#products#p-3$/', $matches)) {
    if (!empty($matches[1])) { 
        $res = $matches[1];
    }
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/9nc3oy), the output is `3` as Group 1 matched. In case there is no match, `$res` will keep holding `1`.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me.